# Dynamic filtering in Oracle APEX interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I'm working with Oracle APEX version 23.1.

I have an interactive grid as following

```
item  category
hat1  dark-grey,beanie
hat2  light-grey,beanie
hat3  grey,cap
```

I want to filter item with color `grey` only. What I did is that I used filtering function of interactive grid with operator `contains` and inputed grey. However, this returns all three items including light- and dark-grey, while I'm only interesting in "plain" grey.

Is there any way to modified filtering function of interactive grid so that filtering is done directly from interactive grid and only item hat3 is returned?

It means to not change SQL query of interactive grid and not additional filtering box outside the interactive grid.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you need to use the filtering operator `'equals'` instead of `'contains'`.
[image]

However, as I see from your sample data, when you change it to `'contains'` it will not get you any record when you filter the IG with 'grey' because you have a design flaw in your table that the category column holds multiple data in it.
[image]

To overcome that flaw, I suggest you to use `regexp_substr` in your IG query such as:

```
SELECT
    'hat1'                                           AS item,
    'dark-grey,beanie'                               AS category,
    regexp_substr('dark-grey,beanie', '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS color,
    regexp_substr('dark-grey,beanie', '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS product
FROM
    dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'hat2'                                            AS item,
    'light-grey,beanie'                               AS category,
    regexp_substr('light-grey,beanie', '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS color,
    regexp_substr('light-grey,beanie', '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS product
FROM
    dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'hat3'                                   AS item,
    'grey,cap'                               AS category,
    regexp_substr('grey,cap', '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS color,
    regexp_substr('grey,cap', '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS product
FROM
    dual;
```

Which will result as: [image]

By splitting your category column to two, you can now use the filtering operator `equals` for the `color` column:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Category column might include more properites whose length can be varied among item. Is there other apporach so that I can modify filtering function of interactive grid?

Comment: @Cassie To my knowledge, there is no built-in functionality for what you need. I think you are pretty limited on this table structure and you should normalize it. Another option would be adding region buttons(something like a 'Filter Grey') that submits/refreshes the IG that the IG is filtered on the source level but this is not appropriate to use because then you will need to add multiple buttons for each color etc.